# Angular Material, Mat Chips Autocomplete Bug, matChipInputTokenEnd executed before optionSelected

Tags: angular, angular-material

When typing some text into the input and selecting an option from the autocomplete by hiting enter, it saves as chips both of the strings. [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rIYG.png)

However, this doesn't happen when selecting an option from the autocomplete with the mouse.

In the example provided on [Angular Material Autocomplete Chips](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview), in the case described, the optionSelected fires first, while in the same code on my local machine it is executed after matChipInputTokenEnd, thus, leading to the bug.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Answer (score 7):

it worked for me when I changed the order when importing modules. Import `MatAutocompleteModule` before `MatChipsModule`.

Comment: This was the case for me 

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the selection event, when you press ENTER, both the *matChipInputTokenEnd*, from your input, and the *optionSelected*, from **mat-autocomplete**, will fire. *Normally*, this happens with the *optionSelected* first, so that when the input event fires, the chip will already be added and the input will have no value to add. This is the reason why you don't get this issue by clicking with your mouse, since only the *optionSelected* event will be fired.

Now I said *normally* because I've also been getting this problem on a module imported component. If this is your case, this is probably a bug.

However, I did find a quick solution. What I did was check if the **mat-autocomplete** dialog was open and prevent the **mat-chip-input** from adding a new element. Checking for a selected item on the options list is also a possibility but it's less performant and not the behavior I was looking for.

Hope this helps:

```js
@ViewChild('chipAutocomplete') chipAutocomplete: MatAutocomplete;

addElement(event: MatChipInputEvent) {
  if ((event.value || '').trim() && !this.chipAutocomplete.isOpen) {
    this.value.push({
      name: event.value.trim()
    });
  }

  if (event.input) {
    event.input.value = '';
  }

  this.chipInputControl.setValue(null);
}
```

Comment: I experience the same issue with angular material 9, before with angular material 8 I did not have this... Thanks for the trick

Comment: This will not work if I want to enter a partial tag that matches the tag in the auto complete. Lets say the autocomplete has 'Apples' but I want to apply 'Apple' as the tag, doing this will not apply the 'apple' tag as the autocomplete is still open when apple is typed.

Answer (score 3):

I am on Angular 12. 
In my case removing **[matChipInputAddOnBlur]=true** directive from the input tag did the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Instead of removing  **[matChipInputAddOnBlur]=true** you can also set it to **false**. That also worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

While the solution presented by André Dias works when you have a strict selection choice, it won't do if you need to add a substring of one in the selection (think of "java" when you have only "javascript" in autocomplete). For this also to work you can use the `optionActivated` event with a global variable (**this does not solve completely the problem, you still have the issue if you select with the mouse**). Below an example.
The html part:

```
        <mat-autocomplete
          #auto="matAutocomplete"
          (optionActivated)="optionActivated($event)"
          (optionSelected)="selectedTag($event)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of filteredTags | async" [value]="tag">
            {{ tag }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
```

The component part:

```
  autocompleteTagsOptionActivated = false;

  optionActivated($event: MatAutocompleteActivatedEvent) {
    if ($event.option) {
      this.autocompleteTagsOptionActivated = true;
    }
  }
```

and then check the boolean variable and set it to false when actually added from keyboard selection:

```
  addTag(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    if ((value || '').trim()  && !this.autocompleteTagsOptionActivated) {
      this.formArrayTags.push(this.formBuilder.control(value.trim().toLowerCase()));
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }

    this.tagsControl.setValue(null);
    this.formArrayTags.markAsDirty();
  }
```

```
  selectedTag(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    this.formArrayTags.push(this.formBuilder.control(event.option.viewValue));
    this.tagInput.nativeElement.value = '';
    this.tagsControl.setValue(null);
    this.autocompleteTagsOptionActivated = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined the answer from @ama and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61420315/matautocomplete-how-to-stop-opening-of-matautocomplete-in-mat-chip-list-when-a) to get the functionality I think you're describing.  The key was to combine the optionActivated global variable with manually closing the autocomplete panel:

1. Add `optionActivated` to your `mat-autocomplete`

```
<input #autoInput (matChipInputTokenEnd)="inputTokenEnd($event)" ... >
<mat-autocomplete (optionActivated)="optionActivated($event)"
                  (optionSelected)="optionSelected($event)... >
```

2. Add the `optionActivated` function and global var

```
autocompleteTagsOptionActivated = false;

  optionActivated(event: MatAutocompleteActivatedEvent) {
    if (event.option) {
      this.autocompleteTagsOptionActivated = true;
    }
  }
```

3. Add a accessor for the `MatAutocompleteTrigger` of your input

```
@ViewChild('autoInput', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger }) matAutocompleteTrigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```

4. Alter your `inputTokenEnd` to only process the input if there tags weren't activated and conditionally close the autocomplete

```
  inputTokenEnd(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    if ((value || '').trim() && !this.autocompleteTagsOptionActivated) {   
      this.value.push(value.trim());
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
    this.controlsForm.autocomplete.setValue(null);

    // If no autocomplete options were activated, then issue the command to close the panel.  The enter key that
    // triggers the input will inadventantly open the panel
    if (!this.autocompleteTagsOptionActivated) {
      this.matAutocompleteTrigger.closePanel()
    } 
  }
```

5. Alter your `optionSelected` to reset the activation var

```
  optionSelected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent): void {
    this.autocompleteTagsOptionActivated = false;

    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same behavior and the solution was simply put the `[matAutocomplete]` before `[matChipInputFor]`

Answer (score 0):

Setting [matChipInputAddOnBlur] to false (or deleting it) can solve the issue.

When set to true it means that an event is emitted when the element is blurred, eg it's not on focus anymore.

That's why the event is emitted from the input when you click on the dropdown.

[https://v6.material.angular.io/components/chips/api#:~:text=Whether%20or%20not%20the%20chipEnd%20event%20will%20be%20emitted%20when%20the%20input%20is%20blurred](https://v6.material.angular.io/components/chips/api#:%7E:text=Whether%20or%20not%20the%20chipEnd%20event%20will%20be%20emitted%20when%20the%20input%20is%20blurred).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event